# Override module class method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to override a class method in a module that has been provided by a third party.

My goal is to check for the second argument, if it's a Hash then instantiate a new custom object, otherwise call the original implementation:

```
module ThirdParty
  def self.login(email, password_or_options)
    if password_or_options.is_a?(Hash)
      SafeSession.new(email, password_or_options['sid'], password_or_options['master_key'], password_or_options['shared_keys'], password_or_options['rsa_privk']).storage
    else
      super(email, password_or_options)
    end
  end
```

Original method signature:

```
module ThirdParty
  def self.login(email, password)
    # Library doing its own stuff
  end
end
```

At the moment this is failing with

```
ThirdParty.login('email', { test: true })
NoMethodError: super: no superclass method `login' for ThirdParty:Module
```

I'm also using ActiveSupport, in case there's a solution to this problem in this framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
module ThirdParty
  class << self
    def login_with_change(email, password_or_options)
      if password_or_options.is_a?(Hash)
        SafeSession.new(email, options['sid'], password_or_options['master_key'], password_or_options['shared_keys'], password_or_options['rsa_privk']).storage
      else
        login_without_change(email, password_or_options)
      end
    end
    alias_method_chain :login, :change
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm getting `undefined method 'login' for class 'Module'` on the `alias_method_chain` line. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure then `login` method is defined within ThirdParty login and not within one of the modules included within it?

Comment: At this point I'm not sure. The code I'm trying to override is this: https://github.com/topac/rmega/blob/master/lib/rmega/session.rb#L7

Comment: So `ThirdParty` is really `Rmega`?

Comment: yes, I didn't specify the lib name in question because I thought it would not be relevant :) Thanks.

Comment: yes, it is a gem bundled with bundler, also I `require` it explicitly. Maybe something to do with Rails conventions? I'm quickly hacking this code in a file in `/lib`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54274/discussion-between-broisatse-and-john-smith).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will work
use alias_method to alias the original method in monkey_patched module

```
 module ThirdParty
   class << self
     alias_method :login_ori, :login
   end
   def self.login(email, password_or_options)
     if password_or_options.is_a?(Hash)
       SafeSession.new(email, password_or_options['sid'], password_or_options['master_key'], password_or_options['shared_keys'], password_or_options['rsa_privk']).storage
     else
       login_ori(email, password_or_options)
     end
   end
 end
```